# Defining a torus $T$ a certain way, prove that $T\cong (k^*)^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups

### The Question:

> Suppose we are given the definition that a torus $T$ of a linear algebraic group over $k$ is a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb D_n$, show that $$T\cong(k^*)^m$$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$.

*NB:* Here $\Bbb D_n$ is the group of nonsingular, diagonal $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $k$.

### Context:

I have looked in Springer, Borel, and Humphreys; a proof is nowhere obvious in them. The text *"Linear Algebraic Groups"*, by Tom De Medts doesn't prove it (as far as I can tell). Herzig's text of the same name *defines* the theorem into existence. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3ATorus%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24T%5Ccong%20(k%5E*)%5En%24&p=2) and [this MSE search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Tous+diagonalisable+isomorphic+), this question is new to MSE.

*Why am I asking?*

Because I'm studying for a postgraduate research degree in linear algebraic groups. I am writing a report, and part of the process of doing so entails revision of the basic material.

### Thoughts:

My intuition is that I "simply" need to argue in terms of the dimension of $\Bbb D_n$.

Wouldn't it be $T\cong \Bbb D_n\cong (k^*)^{n-1}$, since $\Bbb D_n$ is the group of *nonsingular* diagonal matrices? (The $n$th entry is determined by the first $(n-1)$th entries along the diagonal.)

---

Please help :)

Comment: I don’t understand your question… isn’t $T$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{D}_n$? And $\mathbb{D}_n$ isomorphic to $(k^{\times})^n$?

Comment: Obviously $\mathbb D_n \cong (k^*)^n$. The isomorphism sends the diagonal matrix with entries $x_1, \dots, x_n$ to $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. What is difficult?

Comment: It seems like you understand it well enough, @Aphelli. Perhaps I was overthinking it. I invite you to answer the  question.

Comment: I was ovethinking it, @SeanEberhard. Thank you. If you want, I'd accept an answer from you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $T\cong \Bbb D_n\cong (k^*)^{n-1}$, since $\Bbb D_n$ is the group of *nonsingular* diagonal matrices, @SeanEberhard?

Comment: No, for nonsingularity you just need the entries to be all nonzero. Perhaps you are thinking of $\mathbb D_n \cap \mathrm{SL}_n$.

Comment: Ah, of course! That's probably why I've been stuck. Okay, I've got it now. Thank you, @SeanEberhard.

Comment: It would be more normal for the claim to be that $T$ is a torus if it is isomorphic to a closed connected subgroup of $\mathbb D_n$. Statements of that form should be in Milne's book I think.